# Abstract Class with mixin dart flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I following a toturiel on how to use Data Class & Union in One Dart Package on Youtube
I come across this lines of code

```
@immutable
abstract class User with _$User {
  const factory User(String name, int age) = _User;
}
```

---

don't under why he use this  ' _$User "
and what is this line means
  const factory User(String name, int age) = _User;
Please help and thank you

Answer (score 0):

its an annotation from code-generators.

you can change _$User to _$Something and it will generate the same in partial file.
how to use and how it works depends on what code-generator package you used.

[for more info](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#-readme-tab-)